# Capturing all windows messages to an application

Tags: delphi, winapi

Is there a global WinProc for all windows in an application or a way to capture all paint messages to the application for a brief period of time? Some of the third party libraries that we use add their own wndproc's to controls (e.g. DevExpress ribbon, Docking Manager).

We have some code that should be run in a background thread but that's not possible at the moment. This code can take a long time to run and obviously the application becomes unresponsive during this time. We can't use things like processmessages because that would result in the code being reentered. To get around this I thought it should be possible to create our own version of ProcessMessages that looks for specific messages. The idea is that I would create a small panel with a progress bar and a cancel button and then only allow messages for the cancel button's windows handle.

The simplified code to process a single message looks something like this:

```
begin
  if PeekMessage(aMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) then
  begin
    Unicode := (aMsg.hwnd = 0) or IsWindowUnicode(aMsg.hwnd);
    if Unicode then
      MsgExists := PeekMessageW(aMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)
    else
      MsgExists := PeekMessageA(aMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);

    if MsgExists then
    begin
      Result := True;
      if aMsg.hwnd = aButtonWindowsHandle then
      begin
        TranslateMessage(aMsg);
        if Unicode then
          DispatchMessageW(aMsg)
        else
          DispatchMessageA(aMsg);
      end
      else
      begin
        // WM_PAINT is a special message. If you don't handle a WM_PAINT
        // then windows will just stick it back in the queue again.
        if (aMsg.message = WM_PAINT) and (aMsg.hwnd <> 0) then
        begin
          // Queue this paint message so we do an update when the
          // processing is finished.
          FQueuedPaintMessages.Add(aMsg);
          // Paint nothing here otherwise Windows will send it again and
          // insist that we paint it.
          if BeginPaint(aMsg.hwnd, paintStruct) <> 0 then
            EndPaint(aMsg.hwnd, paintStruct);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This is called as follows:

```
while ProcessMessage(msg) do {loop};
```

This appeared to work correctly but during testing I picked up a couple of cases where one of the Windows API calls (PeekMeesage, TranslateMessage, DispatchMessage, or the two painting calls) is triggering a call back to our docking control's WndProc via KiUserCallbackDispatcher in ntdll.dll. The docking control is ultimately triggering a paint which is a problem. I am not sure what Windows API call it is because the stack trace is missing some lines at that point. It only happens on one of our test machines so I can't put in a breakpoint.

I am aware that this is far from an ideal solution and that we would be better off rewriting the code so that it can be run in a background thread but that would be a huge amount of work and is not feasible at this time.

It looks like SetWindowsHookEx with WH_MOUSE_LL might be a solution but that still needs a message loop.

Comment: None of this can be made to work reliably with reasonable effort. It's just a clumsy attempt at fighting the system, and the system is going to win that one. Just fix your application and don't run around installing a heavy-handed workaround, that people **will** start using over time and then there is no way for you to go back, and remove it. You don't fight technical debt by accruing more technical debt.

Comment: @IInspectable There is a project in process to break the code from the UI but unfortunately, that's a 1 year project. I was hoping to find a work around that would give customers a way of cancelling the long running process before then. This would certainly not be something that people would start using over time.

Comment: Just display a different window before all this starts (explaining that the program becomes unresponsive), hide your current window, then let it roll. Afterwards restore the current window. That should be workaround enough for an "at the moment" excuse of not being able to stuff all that into its own thread.

Comment: Can just clear the update region instead of the Begin/EndPaint pair, although I don't understand what purpose that part of the code serves.

Comment: If it's to suppress updating window contents, you can use WM_SETREDRAW for that.

Comment: i would say: if your current code runs in main thread: your message loop will do nothing.. because it can only run if your block goes into application.processmessages.... which reenters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so much an answer to your question than maybe a potential solution to your problem...

Instead of having a panel with a "cancel" button, instead display a label saying "Press and hold ESC to cancel process".  Then, within your process you can get the status of the ESC key by calling GetAsyncKeyState at regular interval. I did not test it, but I'd expect it to work at least "well enough" for your needs.

Comment: VBA always offered `CTRL+Pause` as key combination to abort execution (in contrast to [`CTRL+C` to for console processes in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C)).

Comment: @AmigoJack I used ESC in my example, but any key/key combination can be used.  ESC is just a more natural choice to me.

Comment: This worked really well. We are able to check the key state and were already displaying a message.

Comment: Well that is an interesting approach to allow user still some control of the application whose UI is stuck waiting for main thread to process all of the window messages. Will come in handy in some prototyping projects of mine where I don't care enough to move lengthy processing into a separate thread. No more need to kill the whole application from IDE in order to cancel the lengthy processing.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer gave me a solution to my problem but @IInspectable answered the question about catching all of the paint messages. So for other people looking at that question. The answer is this:

"None of this can be made to work reliably with reasonable effort. It's just a clumsy attempt at fighting the system, and the system is going to win that one."

In other words. Don't try and do it.